# Compiler Error 'User defined type not defined' at line of DLL declaration from VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am a beginner to VBA,
I declare a DLL function with pointer variable in VBA7, the error highlighted at the code line below.

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function USBIO_I2cRead Lib "usb2uis.dll" Alias "_USBIO_I2cRead@24" _
(ByVal byIndex As Byte, ByVal byDevAddr As Byte, _
ByRef lpParaBuffer As Byte, ByVal byParaSize As Byte, _
ByRef lpReadBuffer As Byte, ByVal wReadSize As Short) As Boolean
```

It is copied from VS2010 and modified, the original code is below

```
Public Declare Function USBIO_I2cRead Lib "usb2uis.dll" Alias "_USBIO_I2cRead@24" (ByVal byIndex As Byte, ByVal byDevAddr As Byte, ByVal lpParaBuffer() As Byte, ByVal byParaSize As Byte, ByVal lpReadBuffer() As Byte, ByVal wReadSize As Short) As Boolean
```

I tried in tool-> reference, tick `MS Active Data Objects 6.1 Library`, doesn't solve the problem.

Can any one advise what goes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VB.NET, found in VS 2010, has nothing to do with VBA, [7 or not](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050930-10/?p=33983). They are different languages.

You have almost correctly translated the function signature, including the byte arrays. You just need to make `ByVal wReadSize` `As Integer`, and the entire function `As Long`.

Referencing MS Active Data Objects 6.1 Library has absolutely nothing to do with it.

Comment: after I made change to be ByVal wReadSize As Integer, the compiler error is gone. just want to the reason why the entire function to be 'as long' as VBA has boolean data type, Is it not compatible with VB?

Comment: @guojiwang VBA's `Boolean` is two bytes in size. Win API's `BOOL` is four.